# Puma does not open Let's Encrypt certificates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, puma, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to launch a Ruby on Rails app hosted on Digital Ocean with Nginx, Puma and Let's Encrypt to have an SSL certificate.
The problem is that Puma does not find the certificate. I guess it's because I need to be a root, and not a simple user, to open the folder where the certificate is.

But how can I do to tell Puma where the certificate is if it does not have enough rights to open it? I tried to change that doing `chmod 755 path/to/certificate` and reload Puma but it does nothing.

We I run `puma -C config/puma.rb` on the server, here is the answer:

```
[8018] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[8018] * Version 2.16.0 (ruby 2.2.3-p173), codename: Midwinter Nights Trance
[8018] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
[8018] * Environment: production
[8018] * Process workers: 1
[8018] * Phased restart available
[8018] * Listening on unix:///home/path/to/app/shared/sockets/puma.sock
/home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/minissl.rb:128:in `key=': No such key file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/path/to/cert/privkey.pem' (ArgumentError)
    from /home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:155:in `block in parse'
    from /home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:84:in `each'
    from /home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:84:in `parse'
    from /home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:341:in `run'
    from /home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:214:in `run'
    from /home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    from /home/userlambda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
```

If I try to do `sudo puma -C config/puma.rb`, the answer is `sudo: puma: command not found`.

I was able to see the certificate doing `sudo vi path/to/certificate` but not doing only `vi/path/to/certificate`.

I'm completely stuck at that point because I tried all I could do. Anyone has a clue?

Thanks!!

---

*nginx file*

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/path/to/app/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /home/path/to/app/public;

    location /images {
        alias /home/path/to/app/public/images/;
    }

    location /system {
        alias /home/path/to/app/public/system/;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass https://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/path/to/cert/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/path/to/cert/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

*puma.rb*

```
workers 1
threads 1, 6
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

bind 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/path/to/cert/privkey.pem&cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/path/to/cert/fullchain.pem'

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

---

RoR version: 4.2.1

Ruby version: 2.2.3

Puma version: 2.16.0

Comment: If anyone faces the same issue one day, I'm sorry to say I did not find the answer. 

I ended up switching to [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) as many of my contacts told me it was easier when using a let's encrypt certificate with Rails. Indeed, it was very fast and easy to install. It worked perfectly.

Comment: It seems to me that you're going about it the wrong way. `nginx` should have handled TLS/SSL while Puma should have run "in the clear" (unencrypted) on the same container / machine (or closed network). Encryption concerns shouldn't be duplicated (encryption should be handled by the server, not the app or the app server).

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you. But if I only configure Nginx for SSL, without telling anything to Puma, it does not work at all. So I guess I missed something indeed... Moving to Passenger was very easy and fast. It worked but I would like to know, just for my knowledge, how to make it work with Puma - if it's possible.

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong here, but I bet it's got something to do with rbenv. For what it's worth, you can check out my working Puma setup here: https://gist.github.com/anon987654321/4532cf8d6c59c1f43ec8973faa031103